# Client certificate authentication for a HTML5 web application (C# HttpServer to handle requests)

Tags: c#, .net, ipad, html, security

have a question about using client certificates to authenticate clients to a server, when requesting data from that server.

I have a web 'application' (HTML5/JavaScript) which requests data from a HttpSever that I have created in C# to handle requests. I want to be able to authenticate that a client  has been grated access (using a certifcate on the device), before sending it the data.

Users access the app via a URL in their browser and it is intended mainly for mobile devices (iPad). What I want to be able to do is to mail a certificate to a client, for them to install on their device (I understand that for iPad this is as simple as clicking the attachment?) and use this when requesting the data to be displayed in the app. This way certificates can be revoked from the server side if needed.

I don't really know a huge amount about certifate security or using them for authentication in HTML5 sites.

How would I go about doing this ? how would the interaction work ? and can you suggest any resources on the internet ?